# Combine rows into one in R

Tags: r, rows

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
ID  Name                m1  m2  m3  m4  m5  m6  m7  m8
37  Grötlingbo Roes II  0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   
37  Grötlingbo Roes II  0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   
37  Grötlingbo Roes II  0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   
123 Hablingbo Havor III 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
123 Hablingbo Havor III 0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   
38  Hablingbo Havor I   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   
38  Hablingbo Havor I   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
38  Hablingbo Havor I   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
38  Hablingbo Havor I   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   
38  Hablingbo Havor I   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0
```

I need to combine rows with the same name and their observations in columns m1 to m8 into one row. Only the row names are identical but not the observations. I know that the observations will not collide because I was already tidying the dataframe before.
Since I don't want to add new columns, I cannot use *pivot_wider*. And I believe the *unite* function is only for uniting columns, not rows. I feel like it could be done with *group_by* but don't know what I need to add.
I was already reading many entries here but did not find an answer to my problem yet. Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `summarize(across())` approach:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(ID, Name) %>%
  summarize(across(starts_with("M"), sum))

`summarise()` regrouping output by 'ID' (override with `.groups` argument)
# A tibble: 3 x 10
# Groups:   ID [3]
     ID Name                       m1    m2    m3    m4    m5    m6    m7    m8
  <dbl> <chr>                   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1    37 "Grötlingbo Roes II"        0     1     1     0     1     0     0     0
2    38 "Hablingbo Havor I"         0     1     1     1     0     1     0     0
3   123 "Hablingbo Havor III"       0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0
```

Comment: Thanks! If I only try the code you sent, I get the same table as I had before. I don't quite understand what this line means: `summarise()` regrouping output by 'ID' (override with `.groups` argument).

Comment: I tried again and now it worked! But in the original table I also have some columns that don't start with an "M" and now they get lost.

Comment: @Hannah - `summarise()` by default removes one level of grouping. I based my solution on your sample. If you have other columns to sum, that would require changing the `across()` call. akrun's answer does not require knowing what those other columns are called.

Comment: thanks! it works if I use summarize(across(where(is.numeric), sum)) too.

Answer (score 0):

In `base R`, use `aggregate`

```
aggregate(.~ ID + Name, df, sum)
```